# From MobileConnect, how to opt out a contact from outbound SMS based on user response

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, triggered-send

I am using a triggered Send SMS that is called from SFDC through trigger using [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm). When user responds 'STOP' I want that SMS should not be sent to that user(i.e the contact in MobileConnect whose subscriberKey is set from REST request) from MobileConnect. How can this be achieved?

I could not find opt-out option anywhere in MobileConnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STOP is default keyword in Mobile Connect - you don't need to implement it and you are not able to disable the functionality. You can read more about them [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_stop_keywords.htm&type=5).

To be able to respond or opt-out the customer needs to know the long code (sender mobile number) that was used by your communication. If this number is available and the customer successfully sends to your sender number, she/he will be fully opted-out from communication from this number (the subscription status on all keywords will be set to "not opted in").

In the payload that is used to send SMS, you have three important values related to the subscription status:

- subscribe
- resubscribe
- keyword (required when `"Subscribe": "true"`)

There are a few cases that are possible:

- `"Subscribe": "false"` - only send to contacts that already exist in Mobile Connect
- `"Subscribe": "true"` - create a mobile subscription if the customer does not exist (you need to then add the `"keyword"` value). The "not opted in" status will be respected and the text message won't be delivered
- `"Subscribe": "true", "Resubscribe": "true"` - This creates the customer in Mobile connect where not available already and should change the subscription status, but this does not work when I tested it (the status stays opted-out)

In your case I would recommend using `"Subscribe": "true"` without the resubscibe parameter.

Comment: Oh, your first line of answer makes it so much clear for me. Just one question, do we need to [create a new STOP keyword](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_create_a_custom_stop_keyword.htm&type=5) as mentioned in docs?

Comment: It's really not necessary. You can do so, if you want to for example create a local language version of the STOP keyword.

Comment: When I receive the SMS, it shows me that it is sent from a number that is different from the short/long code that is embedded in my outbound template. So, if I reply STOP to that I am not opted out and I again get the message. Is my understanding correct, if not please enlighten me.

Comment: Are you in the same country as the long code?

Comment: No. But I am using google voice and have it configured for a USA number. Is the long/short code predefined country wise?

Comment: I see that 69979 and 88769 both are US based short codes used by ExactTarget as mentiond [here](https://usshortcodedirectory.com/directory/short-code-69979/) and [here](https://usshortcodedirectory.com/directory/short-code-69979/). Out of these we have configured 88769. How do we make the SMS sent from 88769...or do we need to change it to 69979?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure how it works, so it would be best to ask support. From what I understood it's possible to configure the sender number somehow, but am not exactly sure if that's true.